# "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: WSDL parsing: Could not load" using ZEND SOAP client

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework

I am having trouble accessing a SOAP service.

I'm using the Zend library, and did the following function:

```
public function boletoApiBB() {
    //$token = $this->boletoApiBBOauth();

    $client = new ZendSoapClient("https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/Processos/Ws/RegistroCobrancaService.serviceagent?wsdl");

   echo " <br> testing <BR>";
   echo("<PRE>");
   print_r($client->getOptions());
   echo " <br> client <BR>";
   print_r($client);
   echo " <br> functions <BR>";
   print_r($client->getFunctions());
   echo("</PRE>");

}
```

The request is returning me the following result

```
testing 
Array
(
    [encoding] => UTF-8
    [soap_version] => 2
    [wsdl] => https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/Processos/Ws/RegistroCobrancaService.serviceagent?wsdl
)

 client! 
Zend\Soap\Client Object
(
    [classmap:protected] => 
    [encoding:protected] => UTF-8
    [faultExceptions:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [lastMethod:protected] => 
    [permanentSoapInputHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [soapClient:protected] => 
    [soapInputHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [soapOutputHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [soapVersion:protected] => 2
    [typemap:protected] => 
    [wsdl:protected] => https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/Processos/Ws/RegistroCobrancaService.serviceagent?wsdl
    [keepAlive:protected] => 
    [sslMethod:protected] => 
    [connectionTimeout:protected] => 
    [localCert:protected] => 
    [location:protected] => 
    [login:protected] => 
    [passphrase:protected] => 
    [password:protected] => 
    [proxyHost:protected] => 
    [proxyLogin:protected] => 
    [proxyPassword:protected] => 
    [proxyPort:protected] => 
    [streamContext:protected] => 
    [style:protected] => 
    [uri:protected] => 
    [use:protected] => 
    [userAgent:protected] => 
    [cacheWsdl:protected] => 
    [compression:protected] => 
    [features:protected] => 
)

 functions 


Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/Processos/Ws/RegistroCobrancaService.serviceagent?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/Processos/Ws/RegistroCobrancaService.serviceagent?wsdl"
 in /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php(33): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://cobranc...', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php(1070): Zend\Soap\Client\Common->__construct(Array, 'https://cobranc...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php(1245): Zend\Soap\Client->initSoapClientObject()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php(1202): Zend\Soap\Client->getSoapClient()
#4 /var/www/html/global/controllers/boletoControllerGlobal.php(1319): Zend\Soap\Client->getFunctions()
#5 /var/www/html/global/System.php(207 in /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php on line 33
```

By reading the SOAP service documentation, there is an OAUTH2 server for authentication. I did the authentication and it returns me a token.

The authentication function:

```
private function boletoApiBBOauth() {
        $client_id = "eyJpZCI6Ijg...";
        $secret_key = "eyJpZCI6IjBj...";
        $authorization = "Basic ".base64_encode($client_id.":".$secret_key);

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://oauth.hm.bb.com.br/oauth/token', 
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'authorization' => $authorization
                ],
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => "client_credentials",
                    'scope' => "cobranca.registro-boletos",
                ]
            ]
        );
        $body = $response->getBody();
        $resposta = json_decode($body, true);
        $token = $resposta["access_token"];
        return $token;
    }
```

I send the authentication request to the URL

https://oauth.hm.bb.com.br/oauth/token.
With the token, I have to send the necessary information to the url

https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/registrarBoleto

Following this pattern:

```
Header

SOAPACTION: registrarBoleto

Authorization:Bearer 
aO2TXKd5Mhsg4zpAs3H7ze0YEgk5TdAMeGgIazrsq5TI8EDdAiSryGz/fcGfhMeGgINeLotO+ndhgHVYOsJx87
g==.9iFwrWb9cxwz8i5Jj+YgB+asAn7jJMeGgIHEFtWj4ES503/BUR2fRHNKREAUT22ysR9sMyEoC2FGx/s7B+
wG/P+L6rHxQiMiXAVzUcOj2h0P30QRCWhZwRhp5EulgfnE3Sm5JYal7cXAG3zIP6NehU5Cx5baeiGEbyO2yR
gzyeAiHQ81TTUqOrCxCcRi6XbafVQJdKkwwbecwV5Wggg1cNHz7dZgPXLZdUPm5FDWRIX2+PrRVPrDdC2fgf
oZl2MHunUL6lkaQ9Cg+oPA0Nj9XSKhMeGgIVG3bR8TXgQNkzn02Rl2wJMybEYZXe9yeIjt3PtB9wR/eLNlxZW
OYu8bbDOEvXJ2hz218co3q1KXA7uLhazDgvI8HR9eVpfu7jM39mGLmmwLb15YXpeSg5TVnyE6sdlt5iHdQhI
snucU7qs9ZzsTBcnZk/GZoGqcSdyFoFRIts4+XdgrpRfs9rycZxNG2oNKSdTG0ZDfwo6puBqZeLMZ15MHzx/Zb
x4urjJnVbcsbHoi2iEjch/nHHdpRSDLJmnQni3Ya24rt3HFqnTFQY5TsEL95w0jxLImRxHjb/PK1b5o9+ST/Dfj8k
MsWzaVZGbVqNkpJ7TVkGtbwQgf/kVS4OLrFM6XDJZLNViGtTzKYBIyuUoJahwBcncwRXkwngdcu23qSjbLM
AXcQxYMloZ/jgA3jLGU7Yn

 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=uft-8


Payload
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:sch="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/bws_registro_cbr/Recursos/XSD/Schema.xsd">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
<sch:requisicao>
 <sch:numeroConvenio>1014051</sch:numeroConvenio>
 <sch:numeroCarteira>17</sch:numeroCarteira>
 <sch:numeroVariacaoCarteira>19</sch:numeroVariacaoCarteira>
 <sch:codigoModalidadeTitulo>1</sch:codigoModalidadeTitulo>
 <sch:dataEmissaoTitulo>01.03.2017</sch:dataEmissaoTitulo>
 <sch:dataVencimentoTitulo>21.11.2017</sch:dataVencimentoTitulo>
 <sch:valorOriginalTitulo>30000</sch:valorOriginalTitulo>
 <sch:codigoTipoDesconto>1</sch:codigoTipoDesconto>
 <sch:dataDescontoTitulo>21.11.2016</sch:dataDescontoTitulo>
 <sch:percentualDescontoTitulo/>
<sch:valorDescontoTitulo>10</sch:valorDescontoTitulo>
 <sch:valorAbatimentoTitulo/>
 <sch:quantidadeDiaProtesto>0</sch:quantidadeDiaProtesto>
 <sch:codigoTipoJuroMora>0</sch:codigoTipoJuroMora>
 <sch:percentualJuroMoraTitulo></sch:percentualJuroMoraTitulo>
 <sch:valorJuroMoraTitulo></sch:valorJuroMoraTitulo>
 <sch:codigoTipoMulta>2</sch:codigoTipoMulta>
 <sch:dataMultaTitulo>22.11.2017</sch:dataMultaTitulo>
 <sch:percentualMultaTitulo>10</sch:percentualMultaTitulo>
 <sch:valorMultaTitulo></sch:valorMultaTitulo>
 <sch:codigoAceiteTitulo>N</sch:codigoAceiteTitulo>
 <sch:codigoTipoTitulo>2</sch:codigoTipoTitulo>
 <sch:textoDescricaoTipoTitulo>DUPLICATA</sch:textoDescricaoTipoTitulo>
 <sch:indicadorPermissaoRecebimentoParcial>N</sch:indicadorPermissaoRecebimentoParcial>
 <sch:textoNumeroTituloBeneficiario>987654321987654</sch:textoNumeroTituloBeneficiario>
 <sch:textoCampoUtilizacaoBeneficiario/>
 <sch:codigoTipoContaCaucao>1</sch:codigoTipoContaCaucao>
 <sch:textoNumeroTituloCliente>00010140510000000000</sch:textoNumeroTituloCliente>
 <sch:textoMensagemBloquetoOcorrencia>Pagamento disponível até a data de vencimento 
</sch:textoMensagemBloquetoOcorrencia>
 <sch:codigoTipoInscricaoPagador>2</sch:codigoTipoInscricaoPagador>
 <sch:numeroInscricaoPagador>73400584000166</sch:numeroInscricaoPagador>
 <sch:nomePagador>MERCADO ANDREAZA DE MACEDO</sch:nomePagador>
 <sch:textoEnderecoPagador>RUA SEM NOME</sch:textoEnderecoPagador>
 <sch:numeroCepPagador>12345678</sch:numeroCepPagador>
 <sch:nomeMunicipioPagador>BRASILIA</sch:nomeMunicipioPagador>
 <sch:nomeBairroPagador>SIA</sch:nomeBairroPagador>
 <sch:siglaUfPagador>DF</sch:siglaUfPagador>
 <sch:textoNumeroTelefonePagador>45619988</sch:textoNumeroTelefonePagador>
 <sch:codigoTipoInscricaoAvalista/>
 <sch:numeroInscricaoAvalista/>
 <sch:nomeAvalistaTitulo/>
 <sch:codigoChaveUsuario>1</sch:codigoChaveUsuario>
 <sch:codigoTipoCanalSolicitacao>5</sch:codigoTipoCanalSolicitacao>
 </sch:requisicao>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm lost in how I should do it.
Could anyone work it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error in the first step of the process, that is fetching the WSDL resource. It's hard to debug this issue but most probable causes are:

- the WSDL url is actually not reachable
- the server uses not trusted HTTPS certificate

Try getting the WSDL with `wget` or `curl` on the same server, ex:

```
curl -vvv "https://cobranca.homologa.bb.com.br:7101/Processos/Ws/RegistroCobrancaService.serviceagent?wsdl"
```

For me it returns the error:

```
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

You can either add this self signed certificate to trusted certificates store on your system, or disable SSL verification by setting the proper stream context on the SOAP client with [setStreamContext](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-soap/blob/master/src/Client.php#L845) method (I don't know what version of Zend Soap client you are using, so maybe there is no such method in your client):

```
$client->setStreamContext(
    stream_context_create(
        [
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer'       => false,
                'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
            ],
        ]
    )
);
```

Of course the solution with disabling SSL verification is not advised on production system. The service you are connecting to should use valid trusted certificate, nowadays it's free and easy to get one for example from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Tank you. save my day.